# Spring can't construct query params from complex object for rest template

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

The question is somewhat different from [Spring's RestTemplate: complex object to query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052637/springs-resttemplate-complex-object-to-query-params)
Suppose there is a request that takes some parameters in the form of an object:

```
@GetMapping("getRoute")
public ActionResult<Response> get(@Validated GetRequest req) {
//do some logic
}
```

The request itself looks like this:

```
public class GetRequest{
    private String firstField;
    private Long secondField;
    private ComplexObject thirdField;

    private static class ComplexObject{
        private String subFirstField;
        private Long subSecondField;
    }
}
```

Therefore, when I execute a query with this object from RestTemplate, I want to get a URI like this:

```
/getRoute?firstField=val&secondField=val&thirdField.subFirstField=val&thirdField.subSecondField=val
```

How can i do this? The object can be absolutely anything.
The bigger question is how to translate such an this object into a MultiValueMap for UriComponentsBuilder.

The solution would be simple if it were a POST request, but I need it for GET.

I only know that the Springfox library uses this approach when it generates the Swagger API, but the logic inside is too complex.
My scenario:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> ActionResult<T> getAction(String relativeUrl, Class<T> responseType, @Nullable Object paramsObject) {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = createUriComponentsBuilder(relativeUrl, paramsObject);
    final ApiErrorCode errorCode;
    try {
        ResponseEntity<ActionResult> responseEntity = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(builder.build().toUri(), ActionResult.class);
        ActionResult responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();

        if (!Objects.requireNonNull(responseBody).isSuccess()) {
            return responseBody;
        }
        return ActionResult.ok(this.mapper.convertValue(responseBody.getValue(), responseType));
    } catch (RestClientException | HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        errorCode = ApiErrorCode.API_CONNECTION_ERROR;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorCode = ApiErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
    return ActionResult.fail(errorCode);
}

private UriComponentsBuilder createUriComponentsBuilder(String relativeUrl, @Nullable Object object) {
    String url = this.baseUrl;
    if (StringUtils.hasText(relativeUrl)) {
        url += relativeUrl;
    }

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
    if (object != null) {
        builder.queryParams(this.convertToMultiValueMap(object));
    }

    return builder;
}

private MultiValueMap<String, String> convertToMultiValueMap(Object object) {
    //todo object to params
}
```

Comment: Have you annotated it with @ModelAttribute ? Also why wouldn't you just set this as a RequestBody and use something like a POST?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I don't need a ModelAttribute. I use the object because it is more convenient to work with it than with RequestParam annotations. Why GET? it has all the advantages derived from the method' semantics (idempotence, safe and caching)

Comment: You only get idempotence and caching if you implement it that way. Not sure what you mean by safe. Either way I'm interpreting it to mean "I wanted to". Anyway, since the various values are just glorified request params, then, just use the `queryParams` methods to pass the various values.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the question is how to get queryParams from the object, do not manually map the object to these parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why I got a downvote. But I tried to make my implementation, perhaps somewhere there may be unforeseen errors.

```
public static LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> toUrlParams(Object value) {
    final LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    final List<Field> declaredFields = getAllFields(value);
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        final String name = field.getName();
        final Object fieldVal = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, value);
        mapFields(params, name, fieldVal);
    }
    return params;
}

private static List<Field> getAllFields(Object t) {
    final List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    Class clazz = t.getClass();
    while (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
        final Field[] declaredFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
            final int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
            if (!(Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) || Modifier.isTransient(modifiers))) {
                fields.add(field);
            }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return fields;
}

private static void mapFields(LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> params,
                              String fieldName,
                              @Nullable Object fieldVal) {
    if (fieldVal != null) {
        final Class<?> fieldClass = fieldVal.getClass();
        if (BeanUtils.isSimpleValueType(fieldClass) || fieldVal instanceof Number || fieldVal instanceof UUID) {
            if (fieldClass.isEnum()) {
                params.add(fieldName, ((Enum) fieldVal).name());
            } else {
                params.add(fieldName, fieldVal.toString());
            }
        } else {
            if (fieldVal instanceof Map) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map is not allowed for url params");
            }
            if (fieldVal instanceof List) {
                final Iterator iterator = ((Iterable) fieldVal).iterator();
                int i = 0;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    final Object iterElement = iterator.next();
                    mapFields(params, fieldName + "[" + i + "]", iterElement);
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                if (fieldVal instanceof Set) {
                    for (Object iterElement : ((Iterable) fieldVal)) {
                        mapFields(params, fieldName, iterElement);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (fieldVal instanceof Collection) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown collection, expected List or Set, but was " + fieldVal.getClass());
                    }
                    if (fieldVal.getClass().isArray()) {
                        final int length = Array.getLength(fieldVal);
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            Object arrayElement = Array.get(fieldVal, i);
                            mapFields(params, fieldName + "[" + i + "]", arrayElement);
                        }
                    } else {
                        final List<Field> declaredFields = getAllFields(fieldVal);

                        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                            final String name = field.getName();
                            final Object nestedField = ReflectionUtils.getField(field, fieldVal);
                            mapFields(params, fieldName + "." + name, nestedField);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```